# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' using linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq

i have write this query for getting sum of marks using linq c# "System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.".

write this query :

```
int Marks = 0; 
 public string maths {get;set} 
Marks = db.Users.Where(t => t.userid == t.Markstb.id).Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Markstb.maths)); // here getting error
```

any one know how can do that please let me know?

Comment: use `.Sum(t => (int)(t.Markstb.maths ?? "0"));`

Comment: no still error getting can not implicitly convert type 'sting' to 'long?'

Comment: now getting like this can not implicitly convert type 'sting' to 'int'

Comment: then add ToList() to Sum in memory. `.ToList().Sum(t => (int)(t.Markstb.maths ?? "0"));`

Comment: no still is same error. i m try convert.toint(32) then resolved issue thanks for the help..

Comment: make sure that `t.Markstb.maths` can be converted to int

Comment: @coderwill: can you first show us what the type of `t.Markstb.maths` is?